# Train travel from Belgrade to Munich

Tags: trains, serbia, refugees

We're planning to travel by train from Belgrade to Munich in mid September. We are planning on buying the tickets when we get there but I'm really concerned about not being able to get tickets because of the number of refugees in the region. Will we have a problem?

Comment: Depends.  Have you already tried getting tickets?  Or are you planning to get them last minute?

Comment: I haven't read much about refugees traveling by train. Looks like foot.

Answer (score 5):

According to recent news reports, there are actually a few hundred (average about 200, peaks around 400) refugees, which arrive daily by train in Munich. Most of them are coming on trains from Hungary or Italy, from which they can travel freely, since the trains stay within the Schengen area.

Without even considering that there are most likely not so many refugees on the trains from Serbia, since they will be refused during immigration control at the Hungarian border, even a number of 400 per day does not make many refugees per train. There are some 10-15 reasonable daily train connections from Hungary and many more from Italy, so there is no reason to expect that any train is filled up with refugees.